# navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices() not display device label on firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, video-streaming, tokbox

I am working on media control functionality. I am displaying device name to select from a dropdown and it's working fine on chrome but on firefox it will not fetching label or device name.

Comment: I am getting same issue on firefox.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To complement the answers, on Firefox, the device labels obtained from `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` will also be set to the blank string in the case where there is no more active `MediaStream`, even though the application has been previously temporarily authorized to access the devices by calling `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()`.

In the code below, the `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` will display the labels first (because the permission was granted from `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()`):

```
let stream = null

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: false})
.then(s => {
  stream = s
  navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(devices => {
    devices.forEach(device => {
      console.log('device.label :', device.label)
    })
  })
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log('Error :', error)
})
```

But if you clear the tracks of the created `MediaStream`, calling `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` again will result in labels being empty:

```
stream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
  track.stop()
})

// No more active MediaStream => empty labels
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(devices => { 
  devices.forEach(device => {
    console.log('device.label :', device.label)
  })
})
```

And you actually have to call `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` again for a temporary permission to access the devices:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: false})
.then(s => {
  navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(devices => {
    devices.forEach(device => {
      console.log('device.label :', device.label)
    })
  })
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log('Error :', error)
})
```

Example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-hawking-hswzi

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDeviceInfo/label

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Stopping the acquired stream before enumerating the devices leads to empty labels (on Firefox). Thanks for your detailed answer.

Comment: This is a complete answer. Thanks.

Comment: Great answer, thankyou. I've extended the example to to show the third block (enumerating with getUserMedia) as solving the blank lablel: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-microservice-rzy2tm?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 15):

`navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` will return an empty label attribute value in the media device info if the respective permissions are not granted.

To make it work, I placed this function after all of the media permissions have been granted so it returns a label attribute value as well.

Comment: It's Working fine for me.

Comment: It will get device label only if permissions are allowed.

Comment: As an addendum to this, if you use [this code sample](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/media-devices#enumeratedevices) to prefill a user's audio and video device list, you can add a refresh button next to the list, which will request the appropriate mic and camera permissions and then allow you to refill the device list with their proper labels if granted. `function refreshDeviceList() { navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true }).then(stream => { stream.getTracks().forEach(t=>t.stop()); fillDeviceList() }) }` (don't forget to handle any errors)

Answer (score 2):

navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices() returns a promise that's fulfilled with an array of MediaDeviceInfo instances.

It worked for me in Firefox 56.0 (64-bit).

You can do something like this:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
.then((data) => {
  console.log('data', data);
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log('error getting MediaDeviceInfo list', err);
});
```

where data is the array that contains the list of all MediaDeviceInfo instances.

more info here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant the permissions first. try this code

```
if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
            console.log('getUserMedia supported.');

            const constraints = {audio: true};
            let chunks = [];

            let onSuccess = function (stream) {

                if (!navigator.mediaDevices || !navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices) {
                    console.log("enumerateDevices() not supported.");
                    return false;
                }

                //List microphones.
                navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(function (devices) {
                    devices.forEach(function (device) {

                        if (device.kind === "audioinput") {
                            console.log(device.label);//Other parameters device.kind/device.deviceId
                        }

                    });
                }).catch(function (err) {
                    console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
                });

            }

            let onError = function (err) {
                console.log('The following error occured: ' + err);
            }

            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(onSuccess, onError);

        } else {
            console.log('getUserMedia not supported on your browser!');
        }
```