# Firefox not displaying media devices on Android

Tags: android, firefox, android-camera, mediadevices

I'm having some problems getting Firefox to display devices through the method *navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()*.

I have read this post on the same issue: [navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices() not display device label on firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46648645/navigator-mediadevices-enumeratedevices-not-display-device-label-on-firefox).

But I'm having this exact issue with Firefox on Android, even though both camera and microphone permissions are granted for Firefox.

The same code works fine in Chrome and displays the 2 cameras available, while Firefox also displays 2 options, but with no labels.

Anyone know what could be the problem?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue

Comment: No I didn't and I also gave up trying to make it work as I recall. I made it work in Chrome and Brave on Android. Probably others work too but I didn't test more. A long time since I worked on that project.