# navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices() does not get multiple audiooutput

Tags: audio-streaming, web-audio-api, mediadevices, enumerate-devices

Project: list all media devices, then select 1 specific audio output device which is different from the default of Windows

I used enumerateDevices(), following many code examples, example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46648645/navigator-mediadevices-enumeratedevices-not-display-device-label-on-firefox), and:

- on Firefox: list of audioinput, videoinput, no audiooutput showed, but only 1 for each (I have 2 inputs, 3 outputs)
- on Chrome, Brave: same list showed, also only 1 for each, and empty kind/label/id (groupId is none-empty though)

code:

```
function checkDevices(devices){
        (async () => {   
  await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true});   
  let devices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();   
  devices.forEach(function (device) {
      console.log(device.kind + ": " + device.label + " id: " + device.groupId);//Other parameters device.kind/device.deviceId
    });
  })();
}
function checkError(err){
    console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
} 
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(checkDevices).catch(checkError);
```

Can someone help?

output Firefox
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHrZw.png)

output Chrome (same on Brave)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9WZy.png)

Comment: you need to share your code so it can be reviewed. no one can help you without seeing what you have done

Comment: @Lee3 thanks, code added, can you help plz?

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason why the code does not work, and some workaround, maybe helpful for others on similar situation:

**Reason:**
enumerateDevices() require both permission from the user and security by the browser (https) to correctly list the available devices. Since the code is located locally, it returns a wrong list and empty label/kind.

**Some workarounds:**

1. publish the html, example, I used https://www.netlify.com/ (free); but if your project is under development, it is not convenient to reupload the html every try. Netlify allows to link to github, so the code can be auto-refreshed
2. use online compiler like [www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com), because the code is running from a website, it works
3. use electron to make desktop application, the code is basically the same as that for web app. don't know about electron? check this video (15min) [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TnXz_nnQZrw)

Hope those help someone!

Comment: Some examples will help.